# Should [revit] and [revit-api] tags be combined?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

AutoDesk Revit is a sort of CAD software used in the building industry. Apparently it can be programmed via an API.

[revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) has 558 questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit)

[revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api) has 608 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api)

But the vast majority seem to have both tags (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brevit-api%5D+%5Brevit%5D+is%3Aq).

The detailed description of the [revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) tag includes "...It has a .NET API that can be used to..." which is somewhat redundant to the purpose of the other tag.

I can't think of any reason questions about Revit *as a tool* would be on-topic here; but maybe there are programming scenarios that do NOT use the API (hypothetically, such as scripting it from the command line). So I suppose that [revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) should be the primary tag, with the [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api) tag redirecting to it.

Comment: One has to make sure the questions [revit NOT revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit+-revit-api)(~200 questions) is  all about the api as well. There seems to be add-ins [tag:pyrevit] but I'm not sure whether they directly use the api or any other feature. Better to get a subject matter opinion

Answer (score 4):

Revit is a piece of software. Officially known as [Autodesk Revit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Revit)

Searching for [[revit] -[revit-api] -[autodesk*] -autodesk](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brevit%5D+-%5Brevit-api%5D+-autodesk+-%5Bautodesk*%5D+is%3Aq)  yields 156 results.

A quick scan of the short summaries of these questions yields no indication that there are other uses of this tag. Hence a synonym would be in place.

Answer (score 2):

More than half (313) of [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api) questions already had the [revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) tag, and of the remaining ones in [revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit), most of them mentioned "API" in the question. Therefore it made more than enough sense to add them as synonyms. There were a couple of off-topic posts that I cleaned up before adding [revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) as the synonym for [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api), that is:

[revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) (× 559) → [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api) (× 611)

I chose [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api) as the master, and [revit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit) as the synonym, as it was in line with the other API tags, and was also the more popular one. As usual, I'll give it a few days before merging the two tags into one.